# How to replace multiple lines with "sed" and convert to JSON?

Tags: sed, replace, json, jq

```
{
  "auth": 'log',
  "appid": 21,
  "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
  "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
}

24/10/2017 12:44:24
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "auth": 'log',
  "appid": 21,
  "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
  "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
}
```

I need to transform a list of jsons delimited by some log lines from a file into a single json . so far i've tried this:

`tac tst.txt | sed '/---------/I,+2 d' | tac > out.json`

and managed to delete the log lines, but I need to replace them with a comma and add them into a list. How can I do this ? or there is any alternative for this using python ?

Comment: Can you put an expected output?

Comment: [{
  "auth": 'log',
  "appid": 21,
  "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
  "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
},
{
  "auth": 'log',
  "appid": 21,
  "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
  "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
}]

Comment: but just the comma instead of the log lines for this command would be ok for me

Comment: Note, `'log'` is NOT valid json value. An additional replacement to `"log"` should be considered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sed`** + **`jq`** solution:

```
sed -E "/^(---|[0-9][0-9])/d; s/'([^']+)'/\"\1\"/" tst.txt | jq -s '' out.json
```

- `/^(---|[0-9][0-9])/d` - delete the unnecessary lines which start either with `---` or 2 digits
- `s/'([^']+)'/\"\1\"/"` - replace a value in single quotes to be a valid JSON value (enclosed in double quotes)
- `jq -s ''` - instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array

---

The `out.json` contents:

```
[
  {
    "auth": "log",
    "appid": 21,
    "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
    "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
  },
  {
    "auth": "log",
    "appid": 21,
    "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
    "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
  }
]
```

Comment: Very helpful, also thank you for introducing me to jq :)

Comment: sry, I accepted yesterday but my JS was disabled, I think now is ok

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the quotes around `log` are corrected to double quotes, using `sed`:

```
sed -e '1s/^/[/' \
    -e '$s/$/]/' \
    -e 's/^-.*$/,/' \
    -e '/^[0-9]/d' file | jq .
```

The `sed` expressions:

1. Insert a `[` in the beginning of the first line of input.
2. Insert a `]` in the end of the last line of input.
3. Replace any line starting with `-` with a single comma.
4. Delete lines starting with any digit.

The call to `jq` is optional (it only sorts out the formatting).

Output:

```
[
  {
    "auth": "log",
    "appid": 21,
    "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
    "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
  },
  {
    "auth": "log",
    "appid": 21,
    "custid": "599c1f910f53ada8468b4567",
    "hwid": "59e719ba0f53adfd6a8b4597"
  }
]
```

---

Short alternative using `jq -s` or `jq --slurp`:

```
sed -e '/^[-0-9]/d' file | jq -s
```